# How to format output of script to have equal number of spaces

Tags: bash, scripts

Here's my script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
declare -a a=(`ls`)
declare -a b=()
declare -a sorted_arr=()

var =0

while [ -n "${a[$var]}" ]
do

    echo "${a[$var]:0:10}              |"
    var=`expr $var + 1`

done
```

This script produces inconsistent spacing

```
another_fi              |
f2.txt              |
file1.txt              |
file3.txt              |
```

What I want is for vertical pipeline symbols to be aligned

```
another_fi             |
f2.txt                 |
file1.txt              |
file3.txt              |
```

Comment: Can you post the code instead of posting its picture?

Comment: Please drop the pictures showing text, replacing them with actual text, then clarify what you want to achieve. Actually at the moment there is no question mark in the entire post.

Comment: Fixed the formatting guys :)

Answer (score 12):

The main reason is because your echo command takes x number of characters from variable and pads 14 spaces. That means total number of chars in output string space won't be consistent.

Instead , you might want to use `printf` with width specifier `%-10s` for left padding like this:

```
bash-4.3$ for i in "${a[@]}"; do     printf "%-10s%-4s|\n"  "${i:0:10}" " "; done
1.wav         |
2.wav         |
3.wav         |
input.txt     |
```

This way whatever variable you have will be made to fit within 10 characters,and to those 10 characters we pad 4. `-` sign makes each string left justified.

Number `-10` in `%-10s` should remain the same to ensure that even if the file is shorter than 10 characters, we still get a 10 character string with spaces padded. But `%-4s` part can be varied. For instance in the example above, `%-4s` will have 4 spaces there, but if we want to have 14 spaces, then use `%-14s`.

---

Note that it's generally recommended against of [parsing output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), which is exactly what you're doing. As alternative, we can use `find` command with `while IFS= read -r -d ''` structure like this:

```
bash-4.3$ find -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file;
> do
>     printf "%-10s%-4s|\n"  "${file:0:10}" " "
> done
./3.wav       |
./1.wav       |
./2.wav       |
./.swp        |
./input.tx    |
```

Note that `find` is recursive, so it works on sub-directories as well. If you want to avoid that, use `-maxdepth 1` option.

Note that `find` also has its own `-printf` option, which may be more efficient to have everything done via one process than two ( that's `find` plus the subshell in which `while` runs ):

```
$ find /bin -type f -printf "%-15f|\n" 2>/dev/null | head -n 5
hostname       |
nc.traditional |
fusermount     |
loadkeys       |
zless          |
```

Ideally what I'd suggest is write everything to temporary file, figure out the longest line ( aka longest filename in the file ) and pad however many spaces you want to there accordingly.

Comment: I ran it but... I want to print is
`./3.wav         |
./1.wav         |
./2.wav         |`

I don't want to include ./randomfi.

Comment: OK I'll fix that in a minute. Hold on

Comment: @최세훈 If the answer solved your question, can you please mark my answer as accepted by checking the gray checkmark on the side.